# Bootstrap fixed navbar with scrolllspy

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

I am trying to implement a top navbar that is fixed to the top with links that work with a scrollspy. My implementation does not seem to work as expected.

The links seem to work and go to the proper section but the highlight of the links never change as you scroll. "mdo" is always selected.

```
<html>
    <head>
       <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
    .section {
        height: 100%;
        padding-top: 51px;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar-example2" style="position: relative;">

<nav id="navbar-example2" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#fat">@fat</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#mdo">@mdo</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<div id="fat" class="section">
    <h4 >@fat</h4>
    <p>Ad leggings keytar, brunch id art party dolor labore. Pitchfork yr enim lo-fi before they sold out qui. Tumblr farm-to-table bicycle rights whatever. Anim keffiyeh carles cardigan. Velit seitan mcsweeney's photo booth 3 wolf moon irure. Cosby sweater lomo jean shorts, williamsburg hoodie minim qui you probably haven't heard of them et cardigan trust fund culpa biodiesel wes anderson aesthetic. Nihil tattooed accusamus, cred irony biodiesel keffiyeh artisan ullamco consequat.</p>
</div>
<div id="mdo" class="section">
    <h4 id="mdo">@mdo</h4>
    <p>Veniam marfa mustache skateboard, adipisicing fugiat velit pitchfork beard. Freegan beard aliqua cupidatat mcsweeney's vero. Cupidatat four loko nisi, ea helvetica nulla carles. Tattooed cosby sweater food truck, mcsweeney's quis non freegan vinyl. Lo-fi wes anderson +1 sartorial. Carles non aesthetic exercitation quis gentrify. Brooklyn adipisicing craft beer vice keytar deserunt.</p>
</div>

</body>

 </html>
```

Comment: i think you need `scrollspy.js` too

Comment: Think its included in bootstrap.min.js

Comment: ah, you're right. but can't reproduce your problem. you may need to see your browser console

Comment: Nothing appears in the console

Comment: The markup works fine (http://codeply.com/go/WcveakUzWU) so it must be the way Bootstrap is being included, or the versions.

Answer (score 1):

I was having problems with this and just got it working on my page.  Check it out at http://intern-dev.obrary.com/manufacturer.

To do this through js, you need three things:

1 - to tag your < body > section appropriately.  Try adding a class.

```
<body class="scroll-area" data-spy="scroll">
```

2 - to tag your navbar appropriately.  Yours looks good.

3 - add the js to the head.  I don't see this in your example.  Try

```
<script>$(document).ready(function(){
$(".scroll-area").scrollspy({target: "#navbar-example2"}) 
});</script>
```